# Посмотреть стили всплывающего окна (tooltip)

Tags: html, firebug, css

Всем привет!
Проблема такая: тултип появляется при наведении на блок, но всплывашка сделана не :hover-стилем, а каким-то хитрым js-код. А мне нужно в FireBug-е как-то посмотреть стили этого всплывающего окна.

Answer (score 1):

Читай про отладку js в firebug. Обрати внимание на Breakpoint. 
Без этого - посмотри код страницы, найди слой "всплывающего окна" и увидишь все стили, используемые для него. Затем посмотри css файлы, там всплывающее окно, вероятно, выделено отдельным блоком.